# Does one need to go to the Russian embassy (in Germany) to apply for the visa?

Tags: visas, germany, indian-citizens, russia

I am an Indian citizen living and working in Germany. I'd like to apply for a Russian visa.

Do I need to go to the Russian embassy personally to apply for the tourist visa, or I can simply post the application stuff?

Comment: You _are_ in Germany, or are you a German National?

Comment: i am not a german national

Comment: What is your nationality?  What is your visa situation in Germany? Are you living in Germany or visiting?

Comment: What does their website say?

Comment: I am indian. I work in germany. I do not know german.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes, the question seems straightforward, the OP is not asking us to second-guess his decision to apply at the Russian embassy in Germany or tell him if he needs a visa, he apparently made this determination himself and just wants to know if he can send a visa application through the mail!

Comment: If you are Indian, and not the German Resident, you have to apply visa in Inia, not in Germany.

Comment: @VMAtm “I work in Germany” suggests the OP is in fact a German resident. But, again, he is not asking about that so it's fair to assume that he is a resident on that basis alone.

Comment: He said that he doesn't know German. I think that he couldn't get a residence with this.

Comment: @VMAtm Of course he can. It's especially the case for highly-qualified professionals (including blue card holders) but also for students. Prior knowledge of the German language is mainly a requirement for family visas/permits and for *permanent* residence (*Niederlassungserlaubnis*) but even in those cases, there are exceptions (EU citizens' family, hardship).

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to go in person as long as your application is straightforward and you have an acceptable invitation.  If the embassy decides your application is not straightforward they will ask you to make an appearance.

Answer (score 1):

Visa for Russia are generally (depending on the city) handled by a visa center, not the embassy.
When I applied for my visa for visiting Russia, I never went to the embassy. However, I had to visit (and leave my passport for a few days) a visa agent. You will almost certainly **not** be able to do this online, as they require your passport as well as some signed documents. A travel or visa agent can manage this for you, if not you need to visit the nearest visa center.

There is no requirement that you personally show up at the visa center, otherwise agents wouldn't be able to do it for you. Your best option would be to find the visa center that handles wherever in Germany you live and call them.